# Batch Delete from tableA based on data on tableB

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to implement a batch delete.
I found this code on the internet:

```
DECLARE @rowcount int = 1
WHILE (@rowcount != 0 ) BEGIN
    DELETE T1
    FROM (SELECT TOP (50) * FROM Orders WHERE OrderCity = @city) T1

    SELECT @rowcount = @@ROWCOUNT
END
```

the idea is to delete all orders from @city

It seems to work fine but on my reality, I need to `delete from Orders where OrderCity in (select ID from SomeOtherTable)`

If I try to do the same, it works but it takes a lot of time because SomeOtherTable will contain around 1.5 million rows and the data is being deleted from the main table, so it doesnt get any smaller (it does not contains cities, its another thing).

I also cant join both tables because it wont run saying that more than one table will be affected.

So basically my question is: Is there anyway to batch delete from tableA where tableA.ID IN (select ID from tableB)

Comment: How about using a CTE to select all IDs (but only IDs) from SomeOtherTable and then deleting the rows from tableA by inner joining with the CTE? This way you won't get any dependencies between the two tables.

Comment: Did you try to `distinctly select ids from someOtherTable` like `select distinct id from someothertable`?

Comment: hi marceln. I get the same message with a CTE: View or function 'T1' is not updatable because the modification affects multiple base tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do it without join as:

```
DELETE tableA
FROM tableB 
WHERE tableA.ID = tableB.ID
```

Comment: ok it may work as an one go delete, but I want to delete in batches. How would you do it?

Comment: @Diego DELETE TOP (50) tableA
FROM tableB 
WHERE tableA.ID = tableB.ID

Answer (score 0):

```
Delete Order
FROM
Order INNER JOIN SomeOtherTable ON Order.OrderCity = SomeOtherTable.ID
```

This could solve your problem

Comment: and how can you do the batch delete?

Comment: In that case Delete TOP will work. I hope you don't want purge (delete all) the table. In that case Truncate will be better. So use Delete TOP(#numberOfRowToDelete) From Order Inner Join SomeotherTable On Order.orderCity = SomeOtherTable.ID.............................................

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to delete based on a join. Try

```
DELETE FROM tableA
FROM tableA A
JOIN tableB B ON A.ID = B.ID
```

Also, if tableB has ~ a million rows, it would really help if you have an index on the ID column.